# How to tell `sqlQuery()` to retrieve all the rows

Tags: r

Im trying to upload to R a query with 16MM rows. Im doing this through `sqlQuery()`.

It works perfectly with queries under 10MM rows, however, it seems to stop working once it goes over 1MM rows even with the statement `set nocount on`.

Is there a reason for this to happen or a solution?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `sqlSave` for uploading data? (I'm assuming the `RODBC` package.)

Comment: i didnt know about the existence of sqlsave. Whats the difference?

Comment: I'd start with the `RODBC` vignette titled [ODBC Connectivity](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/vignettes/RODBC.pdf), found on the [package CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/index.html).